# Can anyone chant saum sanischaraya namha?

Tags: scripture, shiva, krishna, kali, spirituality

I've been listening to a spiritual master(online) he advised to chant om saum shanischaray namha on Saturday for blessin of Saturn can anyone chant this mantra??